# Парсер данных с текста

Tags: php, python, node.js, парсер

Спарсил заказы с почты, они в основном в одном формате.

Есть текс с таким видом

Дата: дата и время

Цена: цена

Количество пасажиров:
количество пасажиров

Возможно ли как то обработать этот текст и вытащить данные для записи в базу? Или все таки глупая идея и лучше переносить заказы?

Comment: А почему бы сразу не парсить и записывать в базу? Л - логика

Comment: @ArchDemon Так я же сразу и хочу записывать в базу, но мне надо обработать текст суть вопроса в этом

Comment: Ну и что вам мешает это сделать? `explode()` или через регулярные выражения `preg_match_all()`